# jQuery plugin with methods & global callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, callback

I want to create a jQuery plugin that has both methods and callbacks, methods work but I can't get the callbacks working, the scope of the callbacks confuses me,

```
(function($)
{
    var methods = {

        create: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                background: '#000',
                onstop: function(){}
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return $(this).each(function(i) {

                console.log('create');

            });

        },
        stop: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                onstop: function(){}
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return $(this).each(function(i) {

                console.log('stop');
                options.onstop.call();

            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(option) {

        if (methods[option]) {
            return methods[option].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof option === 'object' || ! option) {
            return methods.create.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  option + ' does not exist in jQuery.plugin');
        }    
    };

})(jQuery);
```

so in the `<script>`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#start').click( function(){
        $('#myvideo').myplugin('create', { onstop: function(){ console.log('on stop'); } });
    });

    $('#stop').click( function(){
        $('#myvideo').myplugin('stop');
    });

});
```

basically it seems I want to make the onstop: function(){} global to the plugin

/* ======== updated code (see comments) ======== */

```
(function($)
{

    var callbacks = {
        onready: $.Callbacks("once memory unique").add(function() {
            //console.log('onready');
        }),
        ondeny: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
            //console.log('ondeny');
        }),
        onerror: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
            //console.log('onerror');
        }),
        onstop: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
            //console.log('onstop');
        })
    };

    var methods = {

        construct: function(){
        },
        create: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                background: '#000',
                onready: function(){},
                onstop: function(){}
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function(i, elements) {

                for (var prop in options) {
                    if (prop in callbacks) {
                        callbacks[prop].add(options.prop);
                    }
                }

                callbacks.onready.fire();

            });

        },
        stop: function() {

            return this.each(function(i, elements) {
                callbacks.onstop.fire();
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.myplugin = function(option) {

        if (methods[option]) {
            return methods[option].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof option === 'object' || ! option) {
            return methods.construct.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  option + ' does not exist in jQuery.plugin');
        }    
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The callbacks should be set by the user of the plugin, shouldn't they?

Comment: I'd like to keep them accessible as options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a globalOptions variable to store the plugins initialization options as global,

Here's the two files to test things out and use as a stencyl.

jquery.plugin.js
    (function($){

```
    var pluginName = 'myPlugin';

    var globalOptions = '';

    var methods = {

        create: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                color: '#fff',
                oncreate: function(){},
                onchangecolor: function(){},
                onloadpage: function(page){}
            };

            globalOptions = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return $(this).each(function(i, elements) {

                $(elements).data('globalOptions', globalOptions);

                globalOptions.oncreate();

            });

        },
        changeColor: function(){

            return $(this).each(function(i, elements) {

                globalOptions = $(elements).data('globalOptions');
                if (!globalOptions) { $.error('Error: ' + pluginName + ' has not been initialized yet'); return false; }

                $(this).css('background-color', globalOptions.backgroundColor);
                $(this).css('color', globalOptions.color);

                globalOptions.onchangecolor();

            });
        },
        loadPage: function(options){

            return $(this).each(function(i, elements) {

                globalOptions = $(elements).data('globalOptions');
                if (!globalOptions) { $.error('Error: ' + pluginName + ' has not been initialized yet'); return false; }

                globalOptions.onloadpage(options.page);
                location.href = options.page;

            });
        }

    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(option) {

        if (methods[option]) {
            return methods[option].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof option === 'object' || ! option) {
            return methods.create.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Error: Method "' + option + '" does not exist in ' + pluginName);
            return false;
        }    
    };

})(jQuery);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myElement = $('.container').myPlugin({
        color: '#555',
        backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        oncreate: function(){
            console.log('Callback: create');
        },
        onchangecolor: function(){
            console.log('Callback: onchangecolor');
        },
        onloadpage: function(page){
            console.log('Callback: onloadpage = '+page);
        }
    });

    $('.color').click(function(event){
        myElement.myPlugin('changeColor');
    });

    $('.page').click(function(event){
        myElement.myPlugin('loadPage', { page: '#test' });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button class="color">changeColor</button> <button class="page">loadPage</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone has a better way of doing this and a way to add "private" methods, please share. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use some full-fledged [`jQuery.Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) objects:

```
var callbacks = {
    onready: $.Callbacks("once memory unique").add(function() {
        console.log('ready');
    }),
    ondeny: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
        console.log('deny');
    }),
    onerror: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
        console.log('error');
    }),
    onstop: $.Callbacks("unique").add(function() {
        console.log('stop');
    })
};
```

Now, when getting some new options you can do

```
for (var prop in options)
    if (prop in callbacks)
        callbacks[prop].add(options[prop]);
```

And to invoke them just do

```
callbacks.onstop.fire(/*args*/);
```

or, if you care about the context of the callbacks, use [`fireWith`](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.fireWith/).

Comment: This seemed to work at first but I forgot I had another console.log(), I am curious what the "once memory unique" & "unique" and such do? 
I added the callbacks like, onready: $.Callbacks("onready").add(function() { console.log('onready'); }),
I also added them as options in the 'create' method, but they currently don't seem to fire. Still messing with it...

Comment: Okay I found out about the "unique" and such.

Updated the code to what I have now, still the callbacks don't fire.

 `$('#start').click( function(){
  $('#myvideo').myplugin('create', {
   onready: function(){ console.log('!on ready!'); },
   onstop: function(){ console.log('!on stop!'); }
  });
 });`
This does not log

Comment: Oops, fixed a small issue in the loop that adds functions to the callbacks. Btw, I'm not sure whether you want to separate the callbacks for each element on which your plugin is applied, as you can't use the static `callbacks` object then. It is also quite useless to add the callbacks inside the `.each`-loop, as they would only be added again without the `unique` flag.